# MPAndroid line chart distribution difference with iOS

Tags: android, ios, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm currently working on a project where I have to display some data using the MPAndroidChart line Chart. The same requirement is on iOS.

The problem is that even though we are using the same data there is some inconsistency between platforms from a distribution point of view.

This is how it looks on Android.

[image: Android Chart example]

And this is how it looks on iOS.

[image: iOS Chart example]

Even if there is the same data the graph's look different. From the looks of it on iOS there's a real time distribution while on Android not so much. On both platforms we've done the same setup for the line chart so I'm pretty sure this has to do with the way the library was made.

I was not able to find any setting related to data distribution format in Android.

Is there something I can do to make them more alike?